# Angular Universal Slow TTFB - npm run serve:ssr

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

**UPDATE**:

`npm run dev:ssr` (TypeScript version) runs at normal speed, but the built (JavaSscript version) version does not.

---

I have an Angular application - https://github.com/dlist-xyz/website

The TTFB is 3 seconds, compared to 120ms without SSR. I have researched the bug, and have found that it could be caused by timeouts loading on page load, which I don't believe I have.

This happens when I type `npm run serve:ssr` or `node dist/dlist-website/server/main.js` to start the server.

I managed to reproduce this with the same project on Windows 10, and Ubuntu 20.04, with different versions of NodeJS (v12 and v14).

**Angular Version**:

[image: Angular Version]

**Network activity on PC**:

[image: Network Activity]

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same one! if  you did please tell us?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal by design to have a TTFB greater with SSR. But you can optimize it for sure. First thing, i see you don't have compression enable in you express server. You can enable gzip compression adding this to server.ts :

```
import * as compression from 'compression';

const server = express();
server.use(compression());
```

Verify that you're not calling api twice by using transferState to cache the api response.

You can check for your application size with plugins like `webpack-bundle-analyzer`

Comment: Build server has a form of compression by default.